# Hausdorff measure as a limit

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, real-numbers, hausdorff-measure

We define $H_{\delta}^{d}(S):= \inf\Big\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}diam(U_{i})^{d}: S \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}U_{i}, diam(U_{i}) < \delta\Big\}$

where $diam(U):= \sup\{d(x,y): x,y \in U\}$.

$$H^{d}(S):= \sup_{\delta >0}H_{\delta}^{d}(S)$$

Show that $H^{d}(S) = \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^{+}}(S)$.

Attempt:

As $\delta \rightarrow 0$ the infimum is taken over a decreasing set so is getting larger. I then need to take the sup of this, but am not sure how the result then follows?

Comment: Show this:  If $F(t)$ increases as $t>0$ decreases, then $\lim_{t \to 0^+}F(t)$ exists (possibly $+\infty$) and equals $\sup_{t>0} F(t)$.

Comment: @GEdgar I am a little stuck still. Since $F(t)$ increases as $t >0$ decreases we know that there is an infimum value. Since $F(t)$ is increasing it will be bounded above (assuming infinity is allowed to be a bound). Hence it will have a supremum. Therefore the limit exists and is obtained at the supremum. (not sure if this is correct and have struggled to formulate this more mathematically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $t > 0$, set $F(t) = H_{t}^{d}(S)$. Note that $s > t$ implies $F(s) \leq F(t)$. Set $L = \sup_{t > 0}F(t)$. Let $L' < L$ be arbitrary. By definition of $\sup$, there is $s > 0$ such that $L' < F(s) \leq L$. Thus for all $t < s$, $L'  < F(s) \leq F(t) \leq L$. Since $L'$ was arbitrary, this means $\lim_{t \searrow 0}F(t) = L$.

Comment: Thanks. To confirm holds because we are allowed to have $\infty$ as the potential limit? In other words we cannot assume that the function is bounded above (since we might not be in a closed interval) but because the limit can be infinite this issue is overcome.

Comment: @learningmathematics Yes we must allow infinity. That is why I said let $L' < L$ be arbitrary, rather than the more customary let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers